# Any way to correct Rebol build-markup function using bind or whatever?

Tags: rebol

This code below doesn't work because I call build-markup two times one inside each other and using the same Global Template variable. Any way to correct build-markup so that I can pass local Template variable ?

```
Template: {<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Free PHP Gallery - web-templates.nu</title>
<meta name="Description" content="This is a template of a free php gallery." />
<meta name="Keywords" content="template, gallery, php, free" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="gallery/style_gallery.php" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>

<!-- ##### Include your gallery class and gallery between the body-tags ##### 
#
# To add images to your gallery, change the ADD-IMAGES.PHP
# To change the look of the gallery, change the SETTINGS.PHP
#
##### -->

<div class="gallery">
<%do %galleryview.cgi "" %>
</div>

<!-- ##### That's it, just copy and paste the line above ##### -->

</body>
</html>}

print build-markup Template
```

Comment: Why do you need to reference both your templates through a word called Template? What is stopping you using different names?

Comment: By the way, why did you write your question as though there is a problem with the build-markup function? It does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Because that's what encapsulation means. That's why Local Var Context and FUTURE namespace are invented in Rebol 3 no ;)

Comment: There is a problem with build-markup because of that lack of encapsulation. This is a bad-practice. Like when I download some code and bahm all my system crashed because the script uses the same name for a method I used elsewhere I don't even know where as rebol doesn't give the name of the script.

Comment: What lack of encapsulation? The build-markup function takes a single parameter called content within the function. The scope of all parameters is restricted to being within the function.

You have "declared" a global word called Template not the build-markup function.

Comment: OK my mistake forget about this cas, I was asleep :). 

I rather mean the variables used in template which must be global.

Answer (score 1):

`'bind-markup` is a refreshingly short function. It'd be relatively easy to copy it to your own script and add a parameter that would allow you to pass the target context through:

```
build-markup: func [
    ...
    /with scope [word! object!]
]
```

Then within the `'eval` function where the loaded code is evaluated, change the block `try [do val]` to `try [do bind load/all val any [:scope system/words]]`. I believe that should do it.